# how to create a function to toggle only the item clicked?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi :) hope somebody could help me.

I have created a jQuery line to toggle a div (show / hide) and it is working.

But now I'm going to need to use the same HTML structure like 8X more.  I have tried to add $(this) to my code, I haven't got success. Could you please advise?

HTML CODE:
(trigger)

```
<span class="go-span go-left go-button-display">View more <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
```

(div to show / hide)

```
 <div id="go-AR-table" class="go-monthly-data go-menu-hide"> Some text</div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$(".go-button-display").click(function(){
        $("#go-AR-table").toggle();
    });
```

Comment: I it jquery code after the html elements both? Please test this: `$("#go-AR-table").fadeToggle();`

Comment: The click handler needs to implement a rule that associates the element-to-toggle with the element-clicked. As it stands, the question doesn't provide enough information for such a rule to be derived.

Comment: So your structure would be <span></span><div></div><span></span><div></div> all the way down? You need to have a relationship pattern between spans and target divs to write a reusable function

Comment: @RicardoZorzo yes, that would be the new structure. And according to the span I click the div below that span should show /hide.

Comment: I will try to upload a complete example on a fiddle... just give me a couple of minutes. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just want to use the one click function to control the toggling for this same thing, but have it work for 8 different controls that will toggle the corresponding element. The easiest way I can think of is assign each element (`<div>` in this case) an ID, and use a `data-target` attribute to point to the corresponding element to toggle for each control. In other words, using your example, you already have the `#go-AR-table` element, so we would add a property to its toggle controller, so the corresponding `<span>` would look something like this:

```
<span class="go-span go-left go-button-display" data-target="go-AR-table">Toggle AR Table<i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
```

Then, you can use one function to work for all of the elements:

```
$(".go-button-display").click(function(){
  $('#' + $(this).data('target')).toggle();
});
```

So, for two elements, it would look like this - and you can work out the rest for your 8 elements instead of two:

```
<span class="go-span go-left go-button-display" data-target="go-AR-table">Toggle AR Table<i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>

<div id="go-AR-table" class="go-monthly-data go-menu-hide">AR Table</div>

<span class="go-span go-left go-button-display" data-target="go-AP-table">Toggle AP Table<i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>

<div id="go-AP-table" class="go-monthly-data go-menu-hide">AP Table</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/45g4fzn0/

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was trying to achieve.  :)

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Following the discussion with @RicardoZorzo, I made a toggle helper:

```js
$('[data-tggl]').on('click', function(){
  $($(this).data('tggl')).toggle();
})
```

```js
<i data-tggl="any-css-selector">
   Use on any tag, not just i
</i>
```

Have a smile with it:

```js
$('[data-tggl]').on('click', function(){
  $($(this).data('tggl')).toggle();
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.well, .well * {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<span class="btn-group">
  <span class="btn btn-default one" data-tggl=".two">tggl: .two</span>
  <span class="btn btn-primary two" data-tggl=".four">tggl: .four</span>
  <span class="btn btn-info three" data-tggl=".two">tggl: .two</span>
  <span class="btn btn-warning four" data-tggl=".btn:not(.four)">tggl: .btn:not(.four)</span>
  <span class="btn btn-danger" data-tggl="*:not(body,html,.btn-group)">¯\_(ツ)_/¯</span>
</span>

<div class="well">
<button class="btn-large" data-tggl="*:not(body,html,.btn-group)">I knew you'd press it! Press again...</button>
<br />As you can see, it's easy to mess up with this toy... Use wisely!
</div>
```

---

**Initial answer:** As you can see, your code works:

```js
$(".go-button-display").click(function(){
        $("#go-AR-table").toggle();
    });
```

```css
#go-AR-table {display: none;}

body {display: flex;flex-direction:column;align-items:center;
justify-content:center; min-height: 50vh;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="go-span go-left go-button-display">View more <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
<div id="go-AR-table" class="go-monthly-data go-menu-hide"> Some text</div>
```

There are multiple cases why it might not work for you, among which, most common are:

- setting `display:none !important` on that div somewhere in your `CSS`
- not loading `jQuery` before `bootstrap.js`
- not loading `tether.js` if you're using Bootstrap v4.
- you have more than one element with the same `#id` in your page...

If none of the above help, please create a minimal, complete and verifiable example we could inspect.

Answer (score 2):

A pretty simple approach if you follow that structure would be:

```
$(".go-button-display").click(function(){
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
```

Comment: That's dark ages, Ricardo. Why not use `$($(this).data('target')).toggle()`. with `<a href="#" data-target=".selector>#of~.choice">Select anything, even multiple collections!</a>` ?

Comment: Of course thats a much better and scalable solution, that is why i said "if you follow that structure"

Comment: Well, it's too scalable. Safest way would be to use two data- attributes. One to enable it and one for the selector. (or an uncommon attribute name, like `data-tarGet` :)

Comment: Totally agree Andrei ;)

Comment: You broke my interwebs, Ricardo. :) See my answer. Cheers!